# How to calculate the upper bound time complexity (`"big O`") of a recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Suppose I have a recursive function `T`, and I want to calculate the upper bound timer complexity of this function.

T(1) = 3

T(n) = 3T(n/3) + 3.

How can I find the upper bound of the time complexity of T(n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) case [image: formula] where a=3, b=3, c=0.

[image: solution]

I highly recommend the MIT lectures on Algorithms. You can learn more about the Master theorem in [lecture 2](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-2-asymptotic-notation-recurrences-substitution-master-method/)

Answer (score 0):

assume that, n = 3^k

F(0) = 3

F(k) = 3 * F(k-1) + 3

```
 = 3^2 * F(k-2) + 3^2 + 3

 = ...

 = 3^k * F(0) + 3^k + 3^(k-1) + ... + 3

 = 3^(k+1) + 3^k + ... + 3^2 + 3

 = [3^(k+2) - 3] / 2
```

T(n = 3^k) = F(k) = (9 * n - 3) / 2 = O(n)